# python waitress - Kill the inactive connections and threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, waitress

I have a waitress server connected to falcon API:

```
from waitress import serve
import myserver
serve(myserver.api, host='0.0.0.0', channel_timeout=20, cleanup_interval=20, port=8001)
```

The doc says I can use `channel_timeout` to make a connection inactive, and `cleanup_interval` to kill the inactive connections after specified number of seconds.

However, in my case, that not happening.

I have an API that takes huge amount of time - but only sometimes. In those cases, I just want to kill that particular thread.

**PS:** I dont want to increase the number of threads, the default 4 is fine.